# Grafana ElasticSearch Nested document query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, dashboard, grafana, grafana-templating

in **Elasticsearch** we have a document like follows:

```
{
        "_index": "1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2018-11-12 7:00:00 - 2018-11-12 7:30:00",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "start": "2018-11-12 7:00:00"
          "obj1": [
            {
              "key1": "value",
              "key2": "value",
              "key3": "value",
            },
            {
              "key1": "value",
              "key2": "value",
              "key3": "value",
            }
          ],       
        }
      }
```

where **type of obj1 is nested**

In **Grafana's** Dashboard Metrics tab, i am using metric Average and it's value obj1.key1 and grouping by Date histogram using the time field start but the graph is not getting plotted as all the values obtained in the response are null even though they arent null.

***Does Grafana support querying nested structures ? if not, will it do in the future ?***